# Accessing a javascript function placed in IFrame from parent Silverlight

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, iframe

I have got a Silverlight App placed in a html page. The Silverlight object has an id. I create a new IFrame by calling this code

```
            HtmlElement plugin_div = HtmlPage.Plugin.Parent,
                     new_div = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("div"),
                     iframe = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("iframe");
```

Then I set some placement paramenters.

I set the source attribute of the iframe to a page laying in the same (.WEB) location:

`iframe.SetAttribute("src", "/Viewer.htm");`

The Viewer.htm page consists of some JS functions.

I access the Silverlight functions due its id something like this:

```
var slObject = parent.document.getElementById("ID");
slObject.content.Page.callMyFunction();
```

The question is how to call the children function of the IFrame (of the Viewer.htm page).
I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("ViewerIframeID").Invoke(myFunction);
```

or

```
HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("ViewerIframeID").Children.Invoke(myFunction);
```

But nothing does work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `iframe id` so for example if the `id` of your `iframe` is `myIframe` and your function is `myFunction` you can call the function using `JavaScript`:

```
myIframe.myFunction();
```

Comment: But I need to call it with Silverlight

Comment: why don't you define a js function outside the iframe that executes my answer and call that function from silverlight?